# Javascript: calculate average of MAX_VALUE

Tags: javascript, numbers, average

The testing environment passes the following arguments to my getAverage function:

```
assert.equal(tasks.getAverage(Number.MAX_VALUE - 2, Number.MAX_VALUE), Number.MAX_VALUE - 1);
assert.equal(tasks.getAverage(Number.MAX_VALUE, -Number.MAX_VALUE / 2), Number.MAX_VALUE / 4);
```

My code is the following (I took it from [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/compute-average-two-numbers-without-overflow/)):

```
function getAverage(value1, value2) {
  return parseInt(value1 / 2) + parseInt(value2 / 2) + (((value1 % 2) + (value2 % 2)) / 2);
}
```

But the value returned is somehow 16... If I use the basic (a+b)/2, then its `Infinity`. I need to get the numerical infinity value of 1.7976931348623157e+308. How is it possible?

Comment: use Math.floor, rather than parseInt in the get average method

Comment: @himanshurajora now it doesn't work with the test: `value1 = -3, value2 = -3`

Comment: Try this ```  function getAverage(value1, value2) {
  return value1 / 2 + value2 / 2;
} ```

Comment: or read this article https://shekhar14.medium.com/find-the-average-of-two-integer-max-value-94bb356598f6#:~:text=MAX_VALUE%20%3D%202147483647.,also%20the%20value%20of%20Integer.